# Adding ng-boostrap to Angular app makes no effect on HTML controls

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-bootstrap

I have recently tried adding ng-bootstrap to my asp.net mvc with Angular app.
I followed the steps at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started) and I can't get it to work. The controls look like plain html (like I didn't use ng-boostrap at all)
I would appreciate any help.

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': '/node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            'app': '/src/app',

            // angular bundles
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'tslib': 'npm:tslib/tslib.js',
            'bootstrap':                  'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'jquery':                     'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',

            '@progress': 'npm:@progress',
            '@telerik': 'npm:@telerik'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                defaultExtension: 'js',
                meta: {
                    './*.js': {
                        loader: '/src/systemjs-angular-loader.js'
                    }
                }
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, NgbModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <h1>Angular</h1>
        <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
            <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Include your main.ts and perhaps lose the package.json as I don't think it can matter for this.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the package.json and added main.ts
This is all standard code, I am new to angular 4 and simply want to create a nice looking form, so I installed ng-boostrap to achieve that

Comment: I updated the question. The previous issue was resolved by simply clearing the cache. Now I don't get any errors, but ng-bootstrap doesn't do anthing

Comment: Are you including the CSS?

Comment: add     "bootstrap-css-only": "4.0.0-beta.2", in your package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ng-bootstrap documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started), you should not include `bootstrap.min.js` and `jQuery` in your project because

> It is not necessary and might interfere with ng-bootstrap code.

But the main issue is that you didn't include `NgbdDropdownBasic` into your App module declarations:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdDropdownBasic } from './dropdown-basic'; // this

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, NgbModule.forRoot()],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, NgbdDropdownBasic ], // and this
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Each ng-bootstrap entity should be included separately. Want to use Datepicker? include `NgbdDatepickerBasic`, and so on...